# Flutter Firebase Phone Authentication on Android: SMS Code Expires Prematurely

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication

Here's an inline link to [Android app firebase settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWlig.png)
Here's an inline link to [App integrity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se1h9.png)
Here's an inline link to [play console certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUu7k.png)
Here's an inline link to [firebase project settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyolZ.png)
Here's an inline link to [verified vs unverified requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AErU2.png)
Here's an inline link to [Error in the mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frJvG.png)

I am encountering an issue with Firebase phone authentication on Android. Despite setting the code auto-retrieval timeout to 120 seconds, the SMS code consistently expires in less than 30 seconds, prompting the error: 'sms code expired, request a new code' (while entering the code manually).

I have confirmed that the timeout is properly set, and logs indicate that the code is being sent. However, the code expires much sooner than expected. This issue is not present in the iOS implementation, which works as intended.

I've checked the Firebase project settings, app integrity configurations, and the relevant code sections for initializing Firebase and handling the authentication process, but the problem persists.

I tried the following steps

1. Verifying the app integrity and app signing configurations in the Google Play Console.
2. Double-checking the Firebase project settings for any discrepancies.
3. Reviewing the main.dart file to ensure correct implementation of Firebase initialization and authentication logic.
4. Ensuring that the SHA certificate fingerprints are consistent across the Firebase project and Google Play Console.
5. Downloading appropriate google-services.json and uploading it to the project folder.
   Attached are the relevant configuration screens and code snippets with sensitive information masked. I have ensured consistency in the masked areas across different screenshots for clarity.

Could there be a configuration I'm overlooking that affects the SMS code expiration? Has anyone else faced a similar issue, or can provide insight into what might be causing this behavior?

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Ensure Firebase is initialized first
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  await initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
// This code snippet defines a variable named "webRecaptchaSiteKey" which likely stores the site key for a reCAPTCHA widget used on a website.
    webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider('recaptcha-v3-site-key'),
    // webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key',
    // Default provider for Android is the Play Integrity provider. You can use the "AndroidProvider" enum to choose
    // your preferred provider. Choose from:
    // 1. Debug provider
    // 2. Safety Net providerR
    // 3. Play Integrity provider
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.playIntegrity,
    // Default provider for iOS/macOS is the Device Check provider. You can use the "AppleProvider" enum to choose
    // your preferred provider. Choose from:
    // 1. Debug provider
    // 2. Device Check provider
    // 3. App Attest provider
    // 4. App Attest provider with fallback to Device Check provider (App Attest provider is only available on iOS 14.0+, macOS 14.0+)
    appleProvider: AppleProvider.deviceCheck,
  );

  // printAppCheckToken();
  final FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.instance;
  final FirebaseAnalyticsObserver observer =
      FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

```
// File generated by FlutterFire CLI.
// ignore_for_file: lines_longer_than_80_chars, avoid_classes_with_only_static_members
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart' show FirebaseOptions;
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart'
    show defaultTargetPlatform, kIsWeb, TargetPlatform;

/// Default [FirebaseOptions] for use with your Firebase apps.
///
/// Example:
class DefaultFirebaseOptions {
  static FirebaseOptions get currentPlatform {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      throw UnsupportedError(
        'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for web - '
        'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
      );
    }
    switch (defaultTargetPlatform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
        return android;
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
        return ios;
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for macos - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for windows - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions have not been configured for linux - '
          'you can reconfigure this by running the FlutterFire CLI again.',
        );
      default:
        throw UnsupportedError(
          'DefaultFirebaseOptions are not supported for this platform.',
        );
    }
  }

  static const FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyA5lo8V9di-Qsi6edZ2212txMrpWvk6yhA',
    appId: '1:60439083317:android:b2bf552f828d665727f47c',
    messagingSenderId: '60439083317',
    projectId: 'wholesomeetencom',
    storageBucket: 'wholesomeetencom.appspot.com',
  );

  static const FirebaseOptions ios = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyAqCjKjZHdDuziGdbzP4pNFBotpIcJZlV0',
    appId: '1:60439083317:ios:0fb67d91a1ca16e327f47c',
    messagingSenderId: '60439083317',
    projectId: 'wholesomeetencom',
    storageBucket: 'wholesomeetencom.appspot.com',
    androidClientId: '60439083317-0570drp99ul6qapmrq5jpvi2o4f75uq1.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    iosClientId: '60439083317-86uitqj0nm0ih8eil2rq0e4iopr0r030.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    iosBundleId: 'com.example.wholsomeeten',
  );
}
```

```
class PhoneAuthController extends GetxController {
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final phoneNumberController = TextEditingController();
  final countryCodeController = TextEditingController();
  final phoneButtonEnabled = false.obs;
  final otpController = TextEditingController();
  final otpButtonEnabled = false.obs;
  final otpEntered = false.obs;
  final isOtpValid = false.obs;
  final otpLengthCorrect = false.obs;
  final supportText = ''.obs;
  final isOtpSubmitted = false.obs;
  final suffixIconVisible = false.obs;
  String selectedCountryCode = ''; // Set '91' as the default country code
  String verificationId = ''; // Add a new variable for verification ID
  AuthService authService = AuthService();

  Future<bool> sendOTP() async {
    String countryCode = selectedCountryCode;
    String phoneNumber = phoneNumberController.text;
    String fullPhoneNumber = "+$countryCode$phoneNumber";

    await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: fullPhoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        // Handle phone authentication success
        // Example: Navigate to the next screen
        await auth.signInWithCredential(
            credential); // Automatically sign in using the received credential
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        // Handle phone authentication failure
        // Example: Show an error message or take appropriate action
        if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
          print('The provided phone number is not valid.');
        }
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
        // Save the verification ID and resend token for later use
        // Example: Store the verification ID in the controller for OTP verification
        this.verificationId = verificationId; // Store the verification ID
        print('OTP sent at ${DateTime.now()}'); //OTP sent time
        // You can also pass the verification ID to the next screen if needed
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        // Handle code auto-retrieval timeout
        // Example: Show an error message or take appropriate action
        print('auto-retrieval timed out');
      },
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 120),
    );

    return true;
  }

  Future<bool> verifyOTP() async {
    String smsCode = otpController.text.trim();
    otpEntered.value = true;

    if (smsCode.length != 6) {
      isOtpValid.value = false;
      otpLengthCorrect.value = false;
      supportText.value = 'OTP must be 6 digits.';
      return false;
    }

    otpLengthCorrect.value = true;

    if (verificationId.isNotEmpty && smsCode.isNotEmpty) {
      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
        verificationId: verificationId,
        smsCode: smsCode,
      );

      try {
        print('Attempting sign-in at: ${DateTime.now()}');
        UserCredential userCredential =
            await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        print('User credential received.'); // Debug print
        User? user = userCredential.user;
        if (user != null) {
          print('User exists. Sending data to backend.'); // Debug print
          print(user);
          await authService.sendUserDataToBackend(
              user.uid,
              user.displayName ?? '',
              user.email ?? '', // user's phone number
              user.photoURL ?? '',
              'phone', // specify the auth provider
              selectedCountryCode, // user's country code
              phoneNumberController.text
                  .trim(), // user's phone number without country code
              '' //facebook userId placeholder
              );
        } // Handle successful sign-in
        isOtpValid.value = true;
        isOtpSubmitted.value = true;
        print('Data sent to backend. Writing to box.'); // Debug print
        box.write("authProvider", "mobile");
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        print('Sign-in error at: ${DateTime.now()}');
        print('Sign-in error: ${error.toString()}');

        if (error.toString().contains('expired')) {
          supportText.value = 'SMS code expired. Please request a new code.';
        } else {
          supportText.value = 'Incorrect OTP. Try again';
        }

        isOtpValid.value = false;
        isOtpSubmitted.value = true;
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      isOtpValid.value = false;
      isOtpSubmitted.value = false;
      supportText.value = 'Verification ID or SMS code is missing.';
      return false;
    }
  }

  void retriggerOTP() async {
    await sendOTP();
  }

  void updateCountryCode(String code) {
    selectedCountryCode = code;
  }

  void updatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    phoneNumberController.text = phoneNumber;
  }

  void updatePhoneButtonState() {
    final countryNotEmpty = countryCodeController.text.isNotEmpty;
    final phoneNotEmpty = phoneNumberController.text.isNotEmpty;
    final isValidPhoneNumber =
        RegExp(r'^[0-9]{10}$').hasMatch(phoneNumberController.text);
    phoneButtonEnabled.value =
        countryNotEmpty && phoneNotEmpty && isValidPhoneNumber;
  }

  void updateOtpButtonState() {
    String otp = otpController.text.trim();
    if (otp.isNotEmpty) {
      if (otp.length == 6) {
        otpButtonEnabled.value = true;
        suffixIconVisible.value = true;
        otpLengthCorrect.value = true;
      } else {
        otpButtonEnabled.value = false;
        otpLengthCorrect.value = false;
        suffixIconVisible.value = true;
      }
    } else {
      otpButtonEnabled.value = false;
      isOtpValid.value = false;
      otpLengthCorrect.value = false;
      suffixIconVisible.value = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```
11:52:39.602  I  OTP sent at 2023-12-14 11:52:39.602271
11:52:47.904  I  Entering _authStateBuilder with snapshot: User(displayName: null, email: null, isEmailVerified: false, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2022-12-16 12:53:36.839Z, lastSignInTime: 2023-12-14 06:22:46.189Z), phoneNumber: +917601084026, photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: null, email: null, phoneNumber: +917601084026, photoURL: null, providerId: phone, uid: )], refreshToken: null, tenantId: null, uid: JPYUfzuvKzLGoIOENdTYhGQUL0r1)
11:52:47.904  I  Entering fetchUserDataState with user: JPYUfzuvKzLGoIOENdTYhGQUL0r1
11:52:54.281  I  Attempting sign-in at: 2023-12-14 11:52:54.281928
11:52:55.626  I  Sign-in error at: 2023-12-14 11:52:55.626649
11:52:55.626  I  Sign-in error: [firebase_auth/session-expired] The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.
```